# Htaccess doesn't redirect request to php script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have 2 vps :

1. Centos 7 / Php 7.0 / Apache 2.4.6
2. Ubuntu 18 / Php 7.2 / Apache
   2.4.29

Both installed with VestaCP same config (apache as backend , nginx as frontend).

There are same script, which doesnt work on 2nd server.

.htaccess rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(127.0.0.1)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bad|useragents) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) script.php?src=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note :

- apache mod_rewrite is ON and works
- direct execute of script works

What it could be? I tried to debug apache logs, finding reason why request doesnt redirect, but apache `LogLevel debug` haven't shown any errors.

Comment: First thing I'd suspect is the `REMOTE_ADDR` resolving as `127.0.0.1` due to your front-end. Compare the NGINX configurations

Comment: It worked! All REMOTE_ADDR directives doesnt work. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil said, the problem was in `REMOTE_ADDR`

On working server headers:

```
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => CLIENT_IP
[SERVER_NAME] => sitename.org
[SERVER_ADDR] => SERVER_IP
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => CLIENT_IP
```

Not working server:

```
[HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => CLIENT_IP
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => CLIENT_IP
[SERVER_NAME] => sitename.org
[SERVER_ADDR] => SERVER_IP
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => SERVER_IP
```

As you can see, "not working" server returns server IP for header `SERVER_ADDR` and `REMOTE_ADDR`.

So, to make it work, my code is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_REAL_IP} !^(127.0.0.1)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bad|useragents) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) script.php?src=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the question is - how to put clients IP in `REMOTE_ADDR` or better fix .htaccess and change it to `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` ? 
Which way is "the right way" ? I havent find fast solution, for now just changed htaccess to `HTTP_X_REAL_IP`.